# Difference between [] and [Object,Object]

Tags: javascript

I have the below code

```
var temp = [{ "a": "value", "b": "value" }, { "a": "value", "b": "value" }];

> console.log(temp) prints
> [Object,Object]
```

If I pull the same from database/api as below

```
var items = [];

data.forEach(function (item) {
    items.push({ "a": item.a , "b": item.b } );
})

> console.log(items) returns
> []
```

However if I expand the array, it has the same items.

How to push the elements so that the `console.log` prints the same as if in the first case.

[image]

Comment: This is almost certainly a combination of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

Comment: forEach is not async

Comment: Of course not, but the part that the OP has left out almost certainly is ("I pull the same from database/api").

Comment: Thank you, the call was asyc and that created the issue.